# Как можно кэшировать данные в Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin

Подскажите есть ли какой либо способ кэшировать данные приходящие от сервера в проекте Xamarin Forms PCL?

Я находил такие библиотеки:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonkeyCache
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/akavache/

Но они устанавливаются только на каждую платформу Native, в PCL нет возможности установить эти библиотеки

Comment: Имеется в виду PCL - Portable Class Library?

Comment: Alexander Petrov, Верно